# How to retrieve paramaters from child object in JavaFX TreeView?

Tags: java, javafx, casting, treeview

I know that TreeView is homogeneous and can only contain one type of Class.

I want to display an inventory that is filled with objects of class 'Item'. Classes like Weapon, Armor and Consumable extend the class Item because they all share parameters like name, description, weight and value.

Adding the items to my TreeView works but when I try to retrieve the Integer parameter 'damage' from the Weapon class this is not possible because I can only access parameters from the class Item.
Is there a way around this, it's like casting it to Item made it lose information?

```
        Item item = InventoryDisplay.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue();

        if (item.getClass() == Weapon.class) {
             System.out.println(item.damage);    
        }
```

inventoryDisplay is my TreeView object.

Comment: Why don't you just downcast it?

Comment: I'm very new to object oriented programming, you're saying I can cast back to the child class? That's great